# Edirectory ldap Scipt for gcds password sync

Tags: ldap, passwords, synchronization, edirectory

What script can I modify or create to write the nds universal password to an empty attribute to poll for password sync?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NetIQ Identity Manager to do that. It can pick up password changes and write the clear text password to another attribute.

Or you can use the Google Apps integration module to sync the users and their passwords to Google.

Usually I would recommend that you set up a federation with Google using NetIQ Access Manager. That way there is no need to sync passwords.